# Jquery update element value except those in hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a set of same input fields that I update the values with val(). They need to have the same value so that is fine. But some of the input fields are in a hidden div, I don't want to update the values for those fields, but they get updated by my code.

```
<form>
<input name="split_values[]" class="split">
<input name="split_values[]" class="split">
<input name="split_values[]" class="split">
<div class="hidden-div">
<input name="split_values[]" class="split">
</div>
</form>
```

In my Jquery code:

```
$('.split').val(split_amount);
```

So all values get the equal amount. But I don't want the input field in the hidden div to be populated.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
$(".split:not(.hidden-div > .split)").val("your value");
```

This selector will qualify all elements with the class `split` and then disqualify any elements that are children of `hidden-div` and have the class `split`.

Alternatively, if `hidden-div` is actually not visible, then you may use a jQuery selector that filters based upon the visibility of the element:

```
$(".split:visible").val("your value");
```

But be warned that this selector will not perform as well if there are many `split` elements on the page. There are multiple element attributes that jQuery must inspect in order to determine visibility. According to the [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/):

> Elements can be considered hidden for several reasons:
>
> - They have a CSS display value of none.
> - They are form elements with type="hidden".
> - Their width and height are explicitly set to 0. An ancestor element is hidden, so the element is not shown on the page.

Comment: Not working for me. Does the .split class have to be directly under the .hidden-div class? Because mine is nested a little deeper inside.

Comment: ah ok this worked $(".split:not(.hidden-div .split)").val("your value"); rather than this $(".split:not(.hidden-div > .split)").val("your value");

Comment: @ssin Glad to hear you got it working! My first example works ( https://jsfiddle.net/uaxbx50z/ ), but only if `.split` is an immediate child of `.hidden-div` (as in your example above). If you have additional container elements inside `.hidden-div`, then `.split` would no longer be an immediate child and it would not qualify on that element. Removing the `>` caret solves that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [this](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)?

```
$('.split:visible').val(split_amount);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
$('.split).each(function()){ 
   $(this).val()='yours value');
   if($( this).parent().is( "div." )) { 
      $(this).val()=''; 
   } 
}
```